# Counting Apples and Oranges, but the oranges dont get counted. Why?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Im practicing coding on Hackerrank, and I implemented a logic which works for the apples, but not for the oranges. Idk why. Any idea?

```
*//int s = start of the house
// int t = end of the house...
// int a = Apple tree location
// int b = Orange tree location
// Integer apples is a list of numbers.
// Integer oranges is a list numbers aswell.
```

The logic is the following:
If the location of the trees point `int a` and `int b` plus the values of the `List<Integer> apples/oranges` is between `s` and `t`we must increment the counter by one. We use different counter for apples and oranges.

---

```
public static void countApplesAndOranges(int s, int t, int a, int b, List<Integer> apples, List<Integer> oranges) {
    // Write your code here
    int applesOnhouse = 0;
    int orangeOnhouse = 0;
    List<Integer> house = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = s; s < t; s++){
        house.add(i);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < apples.size(); j++){
        if(house.contains(a + apples.get(j))){
            applesOnhouse++;
            }
    }
    for(int z = 0; z < oranges.size(); z++){
        if(house.contains(b + oranges.get(z))){
            orangeOnhouse++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(applesOnhouse);
    System.out.println(orangeOnhouse);
    

    }

}
```

Im kind of a junior, I just cant see why does it work for the apples but not for the oranges. I just want to get deeper into array manipulation, list manipulation and logic.

Comment: Can you give a more meaningful names to those variables? What is their meaning? That's almost as important as learning how to loop arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure we can help you without some example inputs, and your expectation of the results that should be produced.

Comment: the only reason i can think of is that oranges.size() == 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn to debug.

Debugging works like this: You imagine, in precise detail, what your code should be doing. You then check what the code actually does. If it is different, you found a bug. Fix it, and repeat the process. Keep going until the code does exactly what you thought it was going to do.

For example, print out the contents of the `house` list. You'll find that, for, say, `s = 5, t = 8`, your house list is `[5, 5, 5]`. That should make you go: WTF? And then you realize that there's a bug in your code; you should be writing `for (int i = s; i < t; i++)` instead.

That may not be the only big; just keep going with this process. You'll find them all.

Comment: Dude, you are the best.

Comment: Of course, writing clean code to begin with helps a lot.  Fewer lines of code to accomplish the task means fewer lines of code to debug.  In this particular case, constructing the `house` list just to be able to use its `contains()` method seems awfully contrived when each `contains()` invocation could be replaced with a fairly simple expression.

Answer (score -2):

you can use below code and works fine:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the countApplesAndOranges function below.
    static void countApplesAndOranges(int s, int t, int a, int b, int[] apples, int[] oranges) {
        long np= 0;
        long no= 0;
        for(int i=0;i<apples.length;i++){
            if(a+apples[i]>=s && a+apples[i]<=t){
                np++;
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<oranges.length;j++){
            if(b+oranges[j]>=s && b+oranges[j]<=t){
                no++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(np);
        System.out.println(no);
    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] st = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int s = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);

        int t = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);

        String[] ab = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int a = Integer.parseInt(ab[0]);

        int b = Integer.parseInt(ab[1]);

        String[] mn = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        int m = Integer.parseInt(mn[0]);

        int n = Integer.parseInt(mn[1]);

        int[] apples = new int[m];

        String[] applesItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int applesItem = Integer.parseInt(applesItems[i]);
            apples[i] = applesItem;
        }

        int[] oranges = new int[n];

        String[] orangesItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int orangesItem = Integer.parseInt(orangesItems[i]);
            oranges[i] = orangesItem;
        }

        countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alva, but Im trying to understand why the logic applies for the apples, but not for the oranges :)

Comment: This is a harmful answer - the question asker is clearly looking to learn. "Copy / paste this into your editor and hit submit" is not solving the problem they have.

Comment: Spoonfeeding doesnt really help people

Comment: Hi, all we are here to try to help this guy :) with his request, then he can analyze the code and take what he needed. let's be nicer.